# Disable ssr for useMediaQuery for Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, responsive, react-responsive

responsive with Next.js 13

I wanna use this the useMediaQuery

```
import { useMediaQuery } from 'react-responsive'
```

But there is a hydration error like this mentionned in this link ([Hydration failed with react-responsive generate div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76516674/hydration-failed-with-react-responsive-generate-div))

Apparently I need to do something like this, how can I fix it? by disabling ssr

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic"
const MediaQuery = dynamic(() => import("react-responsive"), {
  ssr: false
})
```

Answer (score 0):

next/dynamic doesn't work for me, maybe try using [@artsy/fresnel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@artsy/fresnel) (SSR support) with next.js.

It does require some extra work tho when you use nested css selectors in next.js, because the @artsy/fresnel library inserts div wrappers with their components.